# Delete all files and folders in a folder expect the ones ending with

Tags: php, recursion, delete-file

I was asked to create a cron job that deletes all files and folders from a folder (recursive)
excluding some file extensions.

I have this code (which I found on the web):

```
function rrmdir($dir) {
    $structure = glob(rtrim($dir, "/").'/*');
    if (is_array($structure)) {
        foreach($structure as $file) {
            if (is_dir($file)) rrmdir($file);
            elseif (is_file($file)) unlink($file);
        }
    }
    rmdir($dir);
}
```

Which will remove ANYTHING from the folder specified,
but as said, I need to add exception to in (all '.php' files should not be remove).

Please assume the following structure for folder:

```
FOLDER1
FOLDER2
FOLDER3
FILE1.ZIP
FILE2.ZIP
DONOTDELETE1.PHP
DONOTDELETE2.PHP
```

So, everything should be deleted, except the php files

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are you sure in $file have fullpath with file

Comment: the function is working as is, please see my edit.

Comment: i think $file value  did not match please make sure it same one another think is  $file value have extra space or character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is modified function try with this. this will delete all file except `*.php` OR `*.PHP`
files

```
function rrmdir($dir) {
    $structure = glob(rtrim($dir, "/").'/*');

    $rm_dir_flag = true;

    if (is_array($structure))
    {
        foreach($structure as $file) 
        {
            if (is_dir($file))
            {
                rrmdir($file);
            }
            else if(is_file($file))
            {
                $ext = substr($file, -4);
                if($ext==".php" || $ext==".PHP")
                {
                    $rm_dir_flag = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    unlink($file);
                }   
            }   
        }
    }

    if($rm_dir_flag)
    {
        rmdir($dir);
    }   
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

if you want to protect file with particuar extension you can do this

```
rrmdir($your_directory, ".php");

//or

rrmdir($your_directory, ".pdf");

//or

rrmdir($your_directory, ".jpeg");

function rrmdir($dir, $protect_extension) {

       if(!is_dir($dir))
       {
             return;
       }
       $len = strlen($protect_extension)*(-1);


        $structure = glob(rtrim($dir, "/").'/*');

        $rm_dir_flag = true;

        if (is_array($structure))
        {
            foreach($structure as $file) 
            {
                if (is_dir($file))
                {
                    rrmdir($file, $protect_extension);
                }
                else if(is_file($file))
                {
                    $ext = substr($file, $len);
                    if($ext==$protect_extension || $ext==strtoupper($protect_extension))
                    {
                        $rm_dir_flag = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        unlink($file);
                    }   
                }   
            }
        }

        if($rm_dir_flag)
        {
            rmdir($dir);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: please see my comment to @krish r answer

Comment: @Dementic comment here what yo want to say

Comment: The function should have a parameter to the 'excption files'.

Comment: i guess since you dont have validation that the folder exists, the function fails on non existing directories.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48131/discussion-between-satish-sharma-and-dementic)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, Added `if($ext!='php'){`

```
    function rrmdir($dir) {
        $structure = glob(rtrim($dir, "/").'/*');
        if (is_array($structure)) {
            foreach($structure as $file) {
                if (is_dir($file)){
                    rrmdir($file);
                }elseif(is_file($file)){
                    $info = pathinfo($file);
                    $ext = strtolower($info['extension']);
                    if($ext!='php'){
                        unlink($file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        rmdir($dir);
    }
```

Comment: how would that be different? there is no file extension exception on the call?

Comment: can the exception be added to the call of the function?

Comment: @Krish R if you call every `rmdir($dir)` for every folder what will happen if there is a php file inside that folder?

Comment: the function i posted would delete everything in a folder. including the php files.

Comment: @Satish Sharma, As per the document, to remove the directory, the directory must be empty, So that you can able to remove. Here anyway php files may exists, so in that case I am ignored.